# How to change the font size of the content of the JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox, jtextarea

I'm trying to write a method that changes a text size inside of the JtextArea.

```
JTextArea editorPanel;
Font editorFont;

public void setSize( int size ) {
      editorPanel.setFont( new Font( editorFont.getName(), editorFont.getStyle(), size ) );
 }
```

I have an inner-class ActionListener on another class which look like;

```
class SizeListener implements ActionListener {

      String size;

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         JComboBox cb = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
         size = (String) cb.getSelectedItem();
         int i = Integer.parseInt( size );
         displayFont = display.getEditorFont();
         display.setSize( i );
      }
   }
```

I have implemented this actionlistener to my JComboBox, so that when I choose a new "size" from my ComboBox the text size of the JTextArea should be increased or decreased depending on the choice. Which method or implementation I can use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to derive a new `Font` based on the existing `Font`:

```
JComboBox cb = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
Integer itemSize = (Integer) cb.getSelectedItem();
float fontSize = itemSize.IntValue();
Font font = editorPanel.getFont();
editorPanel.setFont( font.deriveFont( fontSize ) );
```

Note in this case you would add Integer values to the combo box, not String values so there is no need to parse the selected item.